# Count items and get percentage

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I try to calculate the percentage of items from 2 tables.

Tables:

```
operation_systems
id   | title
1001 | Windows
1002 | Apple
1003 | Linux

sub_pref
sub_id | id   | user_id
1      | 1001 | 1
2      | 1001 | 2
3      | 1003 | 1
4      | 1003 | 2
5      | 1003 | 1
6      | 1003 | 2
7      | 1003 | 3
8      | 1003 | 4
9      | 1003 | 5
10     | 1002 | 5
```

The following query is used:

```
SELECT operation_systems.id, operation_systems.title,
COUNT(sub_pref.id) AS count, ROUND( SUM( 100 ) / total ) AS percentage
FROM operation_systems
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total FROM operation_systems)x
LEFT JOIN sub_pref ON sub_pref.id = operation_systems.id
GROUP BY operation_systems.id
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Current result:

```
Apple   | 1 | 33%
Windows | 2 | 33%
Linux   | 7 | 33%
```

Desired result:

```
Apple   | 1 | 10%
Windows | 2 | 20%
Linux   | 7 | 70%
```

How to get the correct percentage?

Comment: I think you need to start by reviewing your arithmetics. `total` is the number of different OSes, so `SUM`(??) 100/total is very rightfully 33.

Comment: why you don't use php yo count it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies in this portion of code:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total FROM operation_systems
```

That will give you the total number of operation_systems i.e. 3, and not the total number of rows in sub_pref that reference each operation_system. As a result you get 33% for the percentage because you are just dividing 100 by 3, three times.

This problem is easier to solve if you reverse the way in which you are thinking about it. You are currently selecting from operation_systems and then pulling data into your query from sub_pref. However, what you really want to do is aggregate the data in sub_pref and then give each result a friendly name, from operation_systems.

I would recommend:

```
SELECT operation_systems.title,
       COUNT(sub_pref.id) AS COUNT,
       ROUND(COUNT(sub_pref.id) * 100 /
               (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM sub_pref)) AS percentage
FROM sub_pref
LEFT JOIN operation_systems ON operation_systems.id = sub_pref.id
GROUP BY sub_pref.id
ORDER BY COUNT DESC
```

I have created [an sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1766/10) with the schema/data you have provided and the above solution. Just hit "Run SQL" to see that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT os.id, os.title, sp.num_sp, os_total.total, ((sp.num_sp / os_total.total) * 100)
FROM operation_systems os
JOIN (
    SELECT id as os_id, COUNT(*) as num_sp
    FROM sub_pref
    GROUP BY id
) sp ON os.id = sp.os_id
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as total
    FROM sub_pref
) os_total
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a easy-to-read query:

```
SELECT title, (COUNT(sub_pref.id) / t.total) * 100 AS percent
FROM operation_systems, sub_pref, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM sub_pref) t
WHERE operation_systems.id = sub_pref.id
GROUP BY sub_pref.id
ORDER BY percent
```

**Working Demo**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab661/3

Answer (score 0):

Another way of achieving it

```
select 
os.id,
os.title,
ROUND( ( cnt / ( select count(*) from sub_pref )*100) ) as percentage
from operation_systems os
inner join (
    select id,count(id) as cnt from sub_pref 
    group by id
)sp
on sp.id = os.id
group by os.id
order by os.title
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bc0b/21